# Unable to run react native project on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am using Mac M1, and when I am trying to do `npm run ios` but getting the below error. No solutions found on the internet solved my issue :( please help

```
The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/fullmad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SagaReserve-hdvaajmlsndpidftnfyqfuxydjqw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SagaReserve.app/SagaReserve normal (in target 'SagaReserve' from project 'SagaReserve')
(1 failure)
```

This is what is everything in the console:
https://pastebin.com/gaCEJRJx

Comment: Can you share the actual error message?

Comment: @UgurEren hi, I have updated the question

Comment: i am facing the same issue did u manage to fix it?

Comment: No just using RN 0.67

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Macbook Pro on M1 for React Native development too. Had some issues with arm64 architecture too.

**Here is what helped me**:
**FIRST**: Exclude arm64 architecture from builds:

1. Open your ios/`*project_name*.xcworkspace` in xcode.
2. Choose your project in the left side of the xcode.
3. Go to `Build Settings`
4. In tabs (Basic/Customized/All) choose `All`
5. Search for 'Excluded'
6. Set all `Excluded Architectures` to `arm64`
   [image: XCode build settings]

**SECOND:** Set XCode to use Rosetta

1. Go to the `Applications` folder in Finder
2. Find XCode
3. Open application menu and select `Get info`
4. Select `Open using Rosetta` [image: Xcode with Rosetta]

Hope it helps you too. Best of luck!

Comment: Hello @WitoDivaro, I'm still getting the above mentioned error after doing the required steps described by you